# Get user-data by username - MyBB

Tags: php, mysql, mybb

I'm integrating MyBB forum with another application that requires users data from MyBB database.
But, the problem is that there is no such function to retrieve user data through username but, we can `get User data By ID`.. now, is there any simple and efficient way to get the user's data by passing the username?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://docs.mybb.com/Fetch_Field.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the user by the username, but there is not an in-build function for it. You can check the ./inc/functions_user.php file, there is a function that is used at registration to check if an user exists by username.

You can use it as reference to code your own.